# How to move logo relative video on program monitor in Adobe CC?

Tags: premiere

How to move a picture like logo which is on one videotrack relative video which is on other videotrack in Adobe Premiere CC? In previous version it was easy to do double click on the picture in program monitor and was possible to move or transform picture like in "freetransform" in Photoshop. But it doesn t work in Adobe CC.

Comment: The double click thing still works. Try clicking *harder* ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood your question correctly (which I'm not certain of, given your poetic writing style that appears to have transcended past the need for meager punctuation), you can still double click the image in the program monitor to get into the 'free transform' mode. I just tested it in the current version of Premiere Pro CC and it works as expected.

Alternatively, you can select the clip that you want to move/scale in the timeline and open the **Effects Control** panel. Click on this icon next to the **Motion** tab:

[image: free transform icon]

This will also enter the free transform mode that allows you to move/scale the clip.

Comment: Not everyone on SO speaks English as a first language. If you're looking for a place to lecture people about their grammar, http://english.stackexchange.com/ is where you need to be.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2017 version I can't see it working anymore either. Yes, I can use effects. But the 'free transform' function seems to be gone. Or maybe someone has a solution in some hidden setting?

Comment: No, it's still there, I just double checked. You do need to have track targeting turned on for the track your clip is in (the track name needs to be blue), but it has always been thus.